# Type 0 Functions in PDF Format; What am I seeing?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript

I'm playing a little bit with PDFs and currently I found an function object that looks like:

```
34 0 obj<</Length 650/FunctionType 0/Filter/FlateDecode/Encode[0 255]/BitsPerSample 8/Domain[0 1]/Size[256]/Range[0 1 0 1 0 1]/Decode[0 1 0 1 0 1]>>stream
H‰DÉi3 €áŸÒS«5´zjiµ(5†ªRuEQ&LŠ†ÆMÓL©+MC‚ îG9Wîk7É&›Í­?£ËR3Ï‡wæ•*A©”(,éiË P@'Ž Å9¥ÊªTŸp›JkÇ©u4z§5œÑúsÆ‰1š1Æd¹`]èˆ³¢íŒÕîþÏŸrx`§ç@. .‚žpC=~·7€ób|AŒÏôŽ1Áã¿¸@ðç`7€ñúü8×çöxQ·ãB=êF\¨q9œì@ì§vØì0Æjƒ!«„lÈj!“4š,“Yo4ë
&Þ¨Õ4:½Z«Wit*µP©•Gj ’+ä
@&$2Å¡T.–ÈÄ‡Ò}±dïàP´/ÞÝ;Øíoïîmíˆ„Û¢MáÎ†p[°¹µ&®
6W×7–WK+ë‹Ëkü¥•…Å•yþ2oa‘7ÏŸãOóæ¹³sSÓ¼Iî,gjæÏ$—ÍáŽ³'ÇÙÖ‡Éb3YæøØ/Ö(ã÷Èsx”14Â þ ÷õ
Ðiýt*m€Jë§Pû(?h½jÏwjw/¥«‡ÒÙÕÛÑÕÓÖÑÝÚÞInëøFno!·‘ZZIÍä&RKcSsC#‰Øð•ø¥©žØPWO$Ôk   õ5µ„Ï5„ªêÚÊêšO•ÕåUe•Ë*JJË‹KÊŠŠK
‹óŠró
sró?ää½ÏÎÉÌÊÎx—õ6#3==#--=5õMJJjrrJRRrbâëW   ‰ñq qqñ/b_>óôItÔã¨GÞ¼q÷NxDøí°°Ð[¡!7n^    ¹rõÚ¥Ëÿ o[„

endstream
```

I iknow it's a type0 sampled function but when I decode the flate-decode stream, I have no idea what I see:

�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������þ�½�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������\u007f��~��}\u007f�|}�{}\u007fy{~yz}wy{vwzuvysuxstwqsupqsopsmoqlmokloijmhjlghjefidfhcdfabe`ad_`b]^`\]_Z[^YZ\XY[VWYTUWRSUQRTPPRNNPMMOKKMIIKGGIFFHEDFCBDBBC@?A>=?<;<:9;8786453121.0/-.-*++()(%&'$%%!\"#\u001f

I know they are consecutive bytes and that I should take samples from there... But why are there unicode characters and strings surrounded by `{}`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what random binary data looks like when you try to treat it as text.

The sample data for a type 0 sampled funciton is binary, if you simply pipe that to a shell, or open it with a text editor, then it'll try to treat it as text. Try opening it with a binary editor instead.

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't make much sense to have some `\u007f` that is clearly unicode, and then some random data an then `(%&'$%%!\"#\u001f` again, that's why I was a bit uncertain of what I was seeing. So some parts make sense, some other don't. In any case, if I data stream has 8 bits per comonent and I read 24bits to make a color it should workd then?

Comment: Well that depends to start with on the colour space. That would only be true for an RGB colour space, not (for example) for a CMYK colour space, let alone a DeviceN space.